# how do you delete the nth element in a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How to write the implementation for the function which takes a number n and a list and removes the element at position n from the list. For example: `remove 0 [1, 2, 3, 4] = [2, 3, 4]`

Here is my attempt:

```hs
import Data.List.Split
remove :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
remove xs = let remove n xs = let (as, bs) = splitAt n xs in as ++ tail bs
```

But it doesn't work and shows me `"Variable not in scope"`.
Does anyone know how to fix it?
Appreciate!!

Comment: But here’s a hint: you can use `take` then `drop` to drop 1 element in the middle of the list. Or use `zip [0..] list` to add the indices to the list, and then `filter` out the index you want to remove.

Comment: What should `remove 8 [1,2,3]` be?

Comment: Minor correction to my hint (since I can’t edit my comment now): For my first suggestion, it’s probably easier to use `splitAt` twice than it is to use `take` then `drop`.

Comment: yeah i used the splitAt with tail but it doesn't work. Could you please check the error in my code? It says variable not in scope

Comment: Please do not put your attempt in the comment section. Put it in the question section, formatted.

Comment: @HansiLuo You shouldn’t need to use `Data.List.Split` — `splitAt` is in Prelude, so you don’t need to import anything. But otherwise your code looks fine.

Comment: Hi i modified it but it still doesn't work and shows me "Variable not in scope".

Comment: @HansiLuo Which variable does it say is not in scope?

Comment: Variable not in scope: remove :: Integer -> [Integer] -> t

Comment: @HansiLuo That’s odd. Do you get this error when you compile your program, when you load it into GHCi, or at some other time?

Comment: @brarn hey yeah it says parse error (possibly indentation or mismatched brackets)

Comment: You have `remove xs = let remove n xs = let (as, bs) = splitAt n xs in as ++ tail bs`, but it should really be `remove n xs = let (as, bs) = splitAt n xs in as ++ tail bs`.

Comment: @Billy Brown that works!!! Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: @HansiLuo I have added my suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a pretty intuitive recursive approach:

```
remove :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
remove _ [] = []
remove 0 (x:xs) = xs
remove n (x:xs) = x : remove (n-1) (xs)
```

Take into account that I am considering the first element to be index 0.
Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Please do not use .png files in your answer.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard so sorry, didn't know, i 'll update it right away.

Comment: Pretty nice. Really good for Haskell idioms for beginners, much thanks 

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have `remove xs = let remove n xs =` at the front of your function, followed by the actual body: `let (as, bs) = splitAt n xs in as ++ tail bs`.

You need to delete the first `remove xs = let` part, to end up with:

```hs
remove :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
remove n xs = let (as, bs) = splitAt n xs in as ++ tail bs
```

Or as less of a one-liner, which might help you see the syntax more clearly:

```hs
remove :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
remove n xs = let (as, bs) = splitAt n xs
               in as ++ tail bs
```

Try reading both options as pure (made-up) syntax:

Original:

```
functionName :: Type1 -> Type2 -> Type2
functionName arg1 = LET ident1 ident2 arg1 = LET letAssignment IN letBody
```

Fixed:

```
functionName :: Type1 -> Type2 -> Type2
functionName arg1 arg2 = LET letAssignment IN letBody
```