# Removing nth index

Tags: haskell

Very new to Haskell here, I need to create a definition that you would pass a list and an index and it would remove the element that is present at the index from the list and return the list back.  Would anyone have any resources or pointers to do this?

```
list = [1 .. 10]
remove(list, 3)


--output = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Thank you very much for any assistance.

Comment: [**`deleteAt`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ilist-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-List-Index.html#v:deleteAt)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do you delete the nth element in a list in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61492874/how-do-you-delete-the-nth-element-in-a-list-in-haskell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
removeN :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
removeN [] _ = []
removeN (x:xs) 0 = xs
removeN (x:xs) n = x:(removeN xs (n-1))
```